# Как 3 аргументом в splice подставлять нужный мне элемент

Tags: javascript

Как мне соединить массив abc и dataRow таким образом, чтобы массив dataRow выглядел [1,a,2,b,3,c,4,a,5,b,6,c,7,a,8,b,9,c,10,a];

Вот к чему я пришел пока что

```
let abc = ['a','b','c'];
let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let itemIndex = 1; itemIndex <= dataRow.length; itemIndex += 2) {
  dataRow.splice(itemIndex,0, abc[0])
}
```

Как мне 3 аргументом в splice подставлять нужный мне элемент их abc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так?

Никакой магии тут нет. Нужно проитерировать массив с конца поскольку вы добавляете элементы в массив и `dataRow.length` постоянно меняется. В прямом проходе проверяется условие в котором есть добавочное вычисление, `dataRow.length`. Для индекса второго массива достаточно брать остаток от деления первого индекса на abc.length

```js
let abc = ['a','b','c'];

let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let itemIndex = dataRow.length; itemIndex > 0; itemIndex -- ) {
    
    dataRow.splice(itemIndex,0, abc[(itemIndex -1 )%abc.length])
}

console.log(dataRow)
```

А в функциональном стиле можно так.

```js
let abc = ['a','b','c'];

let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let result = dataRow.map((item,index)=>[item, abc[index%abc.length]]).flat();

console.log(result)
```

Comment: таким образом, лучше всегда проходиться с конца массива, если он будет меняться в теле цикла?

Comment: @АндрейАндреев Да именно во избежании таких же проблем. При удалении такая же проблема. Лучше удалять с конца и смотреть на индекс. Если Удалять с начала то у вас случиться выход за пределы

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @АндрейКочанов, но прохождение с конца массива никак не поможет заставить этот код работать быстро.

Comment: @Qwertiy да потому что двигать массив вот основная операция

Answer (score 3):

Все перечисленные далее способы имеют линейную асимптотику и не выделяют лишней памяти помимо используемой под результат и нескольких числовых переменных.

Если можно не модифицировать массив, а создать новый, то я бы сделал так:

```js
let abc = ['a','b','c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let res = []

for (let q = 0; q < data.length; ++q) {
  res.push(data[q], abc[q % abc.length])
}

console.log(res.join(" "))
```

Если надо заменить именно на месте, то можно сделать так:

```js
let abc = ['a','b','c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let q = data.length - 1; q >= 0; --q) {
  data[2*q] = data[q]
  data[2*q+1] = abc[q % abc.length]
}

console.log(data.join(" "))
```

Если внезапное обращение по индексу `2*(data.legth-1)` вызывает превращение массива в хэштаблицу (маловероятно на небольших массивах, весьма вероятно на больших, но точно сказать не могу), то можно сначала расширить массив до нужного размера (при этом избегая `data.push(...data)` и аналогов, поскольку они могут вызвать переполнение стека), а потом заполнять:

```js
let abc = ['a','b','c'];
let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let n = data.length

for (let q=0; q<n; ++q) {
  data.push(0)
}

for (let q = n-1; q >= 0; --q) {
  data[2*q] = data[q]
  data[2*q+1] = abc[q % abc.length]
}

console.log(data.join(" "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let abc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const length = dataRow.length
let insert = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  const target = i % abc.length;
  dataRow.splice(insert, 0, abc[target]);
  insert += 2;
}
console.log(dataRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для выбора нужного элемента, достаточно завести еще один счетчик, для массива abc. Для того чтобы счетчик всегда был в границах индексов массива abc, при его увеличении можно брать остаток от деления на длину `abc`: `abcIndex = (abcIndex + 1) % abc.length`

```js
let abc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let itemIndex = 1, abcIndex=0; itemIndex <= dataRow.length; itemIndex += 2, abcIndex = (abcIndex + 1) % abc.length) {

  dataRow.splice(itemIndex, 0, abc[abcIndex]);
}

console.log(dataRow);
```

Также можно обойтись и без `.splice`. Так как каждому элементу необходимо поставить в соответствие два и получить плоский список, можно воспользоваться методом [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let abc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let dataRow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(dataRow.flatMap((d, index) => [d, abc[index % abc.length]]));
```

Comment: благодарю за развернутый ответ)

Comment: Только `flatMap` не меняет исходный массив.

Comment: @Qwertiy, заменить просто переменную и все :)

Comment: @Grundy, это не то же самое.